# What did the Russian ambassador to Japan do during his trip to London?

Tags: 19th-century, russia, social-history, london, individuals

The *[Nadezhda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Russian_circumnavigation)* stopped September 28th, 1803 in Falmouth, Cornwall to obtain salt meat [*Voyage Round the World in the Years 1803, 1804, 1805, & 1806*, pp. 35]. Imperial ambassador to Japan Nikolai Rezanov took the opportunity to go to London [*The First Russian Voyage around the World*, pp. 16] and the ship was forced to wait for him; he returned on October 5th.

What did Rezanov (and, presumably, his suite of gentlemen) do in London in those first couple of days of October 1803?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Rezanov's journal, they spent those days sightseeing and visiting Russian diplomats in London. They visited Westminster abbey, London Tower, Greenwich observatory and Newgate prison, amongst other places.

He doesn't write much about his entourage, save for Horner - expedition's astronomer, who needed to buy his instruments in London. It seems that this was the main reason for visiting London - as soon as astronomical equipment was delivered, Rezanov returned back to Falmouth.

Source: Резанов Н.П. Первое путешествие россиян вокруг света, описанное Н. Резановым / Н.П. Резанов // Отечественные Записки. - № XII; 1824, pp. 25-37 and 328-351, retrieved [here](https://books.google.ru/books?id=JA8YAAAAYAAJ&dq=editions:LCCNsf89090114&lr=&hl=ru&pg=PA1&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) (warning, old Russian)